# AWS hosting large model file for machine learning

Tags: amazon-web-services, machine-learning, hosting

I'd like to expose a model I've trained locally with some functions that help evaluate parameters through it. The model is quite large (10 gb). I thought of building a web service that would expose the required functionality. However, I don't know how I should host my model (it's a very large text file) and how I would be able to access it. Also, taking it one step forward, do I load the entire model into my EC2 instance memory? What would be considered the best way to handle such a task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always keep it in an S3 bucket and load it in R, for example. I cannot see a way to load a model partially, however. I'd say you will loose the model's capability to generalize your results. I am afraid you will need to spend some bucks and take a big instance able to load the entire thing. Good luck!